# Recipe for repeatedly baked meal offering (Vayikra 6:12)

Tags: mincha-meal-offering

Vayikra 6:12 mentions a repeatedly baked meal offering. I am looking for an actual recipe for this.

Answer (score 7):

Rambam describes the process in his *Laws of the Actions of the Offerings*, at the beginning of chapter 13 ([Hebrew](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/8513.htm) | [English](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1017025/jewish/Maaseh-Hakorbanot-Chapter-13.htm)).

> וכיצד עשיית חביתי כוהן גדול:  מביא עישרון שלם, וחוצהו בחצי עישרון
>   שבמקדש--שאף על פי שהיא קרבה חציין, אינה מתקדשת לחציין; ומביא עימה
>   שלושת לוגין שמן--שנאמר "בשמן תיעשה" (ויקרא ו,יד), להוסיף לה שמן כנסכי
>   הכבש.
>
> ובולל הסולת בשמן, וחולט אותה ברותחין, ולש מכל חצי עישרון, שש חלות;
>   נמצאו שתים עשרה חלות.  ואחת אחת היו נעשות.  וכיצד עושה:  מחלק השלושת
>   לוגין ברביעית שבמקדש, רביעית לכל חלה; ואופה החלה מעט, ואחר כך קולה
>   אותה על המחבת בשאר רביעית השמן שלה.  ואינו מבשלה הרבה--שנאמר "תופיני"
>   (ויקרא ו,יד), בין בשל ונא.
>
> ואחר כך חולק כל חלה וחלה לשניים, באומד--כדי שיקריב החצי בבוקר, והחצי
>   בערב; ולוקח החציין, וכופל כל אחד מהן לשניים, ופותת עד שתימצא כל פתיתה
>   כפולה לשניים.  ומקריב החציין עם חצי קומץ לבונה, בבוקר; והחצי הנשאר עם
>   חצי קומץ לבונה, בערב.
>
> How was the chavitin offering of the High Priest prepared? He would
>   bring an entire isaron and sanctify it and then divide it in half with
>   the half isaron measure in the Temple. [This was necessary,] because
>   even though it was offered in half [portions], it was not sanctified
>   in half portions. Three lugim of oil are brought with it, as
>   [Leviticus 6:13] states: "You shall prepare it with oil," i.e., [an
>   amount of] oil equivalent to the accompanying offering for a lamb
>   should be added to it. The flour should be mixed with the oil and then
>   scalded with boiling [liquid].
>
> Each half isaron should be kneaded into six loaves. Thus there are a
>   total of twelve loaves.
>
> [These loaves] were prepared one by one.
>
> How were they prepared? The three lugim of oil would be divided [into
>   twelve] using the measure of a revi'it [of a log] that existed in the
>   Temple, a revi'it for each loaf. The loaf would be baked some and then
>   fried on the flat frying-pan with the remainder of its oil. It should
>   not be cooked very much, for [Leviticus 6:14] uses the term tufinei
>   which implies something between cooked and lightly cooked.
>
> Afterwards, each loaf should be divided into two by approximation, so
>   that half can be offered in the morning and half in the evening. He
>   should take the halves and fold each one of them in half and then
>   divide [the loaves at] the folds so that each flat cake will be folded
>   in half. He then offers the halves with half of a handful of
>   frankincense in the morning and the remaining half with half a handful
>   of frankincense in the evening.

Comment: They brought half loaves as offerings. I would have thought that they would bring full loaves.  Is offering half loaves seen elsewhere?

Comment: @YehudaW Nothing comes to mind at the moment